# How can i call scroll of another android application using my system overlay button

Tags: java, android, user-interface, autoscroll

I am already have created an android service with overlay button and after clicking "Overaly button" - i just want to autoscroll my current android view to bottom (I mean any another APP - like android Sms inbox, facebook messanger and so on).

Also i have tried to simulate touch or drag, BUT no results

P.S - sorry for my english. :)

Comment: show your code be clear

Comment: For "Device autoscroll" a have not some code, because i have no idea how can i implement that functionality :(

If you want a " Service" code - i can show you it

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess you just want to Autoscroll right at the bottom, so this might help if your layout is under a ScrollView

```
 scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
 public void run() {
     scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But i have not any layout and referense on it.
I just want to call scroll of another application using my overlay button - did you understand?

Comment: Ok so you are trying to scroll a view of some other application with the click of the button present in your application. Am I correct ?

Comment: That is not possible at all. You cannot control or perform gestures on other applications present in you phone like facebook or sms app

Comment: I am also can`t get current activity of my native apps? - like sms inbox?